# Limit sum problem

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

$a>1$
Can anyone help me with this limit problem.
I think I sholud use Cesaro - Stolz theorem but,
 I don't know how.

 [image]

Wihout using L'Hospital rule and integration.

Comment: What is $\lim_{n}$?

Comment: $n \to \infty$?

Comment: What do you get, when you try to apply the Cesaro&ndash;Stolz theorem? Or, what is your problem applying it?

Comment: Try differentiating the expression inside the brackets with respect to $a$ for an idea

Comment: @Lovro Here is http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for properly displaying functions.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$
b_n=a+\frac{a^2}{2}+\cdots+\frac{a^n}{n}
$$
and
$$
c_n=\frac{a^{n+1}}{n}.
$$
$c_n$ will be monotonically increasing to $+\infty$ (at least from some $n$ on) since $a>1$. Now I suggest you to study the limit of
$$
\frac{b_{n+1}-b_n}{c_{n+1}-c_n}
$$
and then apply the [theorem of Stolz–Cesàro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem). I will stop here, and hope that you can conclude. If not, I will happily give the full calculations of the limit in the displayed equation above.

**Edit with more steps**

We get
$$
b_{n+1}-b_n=\frac{a^{n+1}}{n+1}
$$
and
$$
c_{n+1}-c_n=\frac{a^{n+2}}{n+1}-\frac{a^{n+1}}{n}.
$$
Thus,
$$
\frac{b_{n+1}-b_n}{c_{n+1}-c_n}=\frac{\frac{1}{n+1}}{\frac{a}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{1}{a-1-\frac{1}{n}}\to\frac{1}{a-1}
$$
as $n\to+\infty$. An application of Stolz–Cesàro gives
$$
\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{b_n}{c_n}=\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{b_{n+1}-b_n}{c_{n+1}-c_n}=\frac{1}{a-1}.
$$

Comment: Can you please write steps solution?

Comment: @Lovro Added more details.

Comment: I don't have the start idea how to begin.

Comment: I don't get what you mean. This is now the _complete_ solution...